# Group by DATETIME ranges on another table

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I have a table that has 2 columns startdatetime and stopdatetime.

```
STARTDATETIME             |         STOPDATETIME          |      ID
2019-05-05T05:00:00Z              2019-05-05T06:00:00Z            1
2019-05-05T07:00:00Z              2019-05-05T08:00:00Z            1
2019-05-05T05:00:00Z              2019-05-05T06:00:00Z            2
2019-05-05T07:00:00Z              2019-05-05T08:00:00Z            2
2019-05-05T08:00:00Z              2019-05-05T10:00:00Z            2
```

A second table has a column with eventdatetime.

```
EVENTDATETIME           |        ID         |       Event
 2019-05-05T05:30:00Z             1                   1
 2019-05-05T05:45:00Z             1                   1
 2019-05-05T07:30:00Z             1                   1
 2019-05-05T07:30:00Z             2                   1
 2019-05-05T07:40:00Z             2                   1
 2019-05-05T07:50:00Z             2                   1
```

I am trying to do a select in the first table and join the second table where the eventdatetime falls in between the row and get the sum of events. What i don't know how to accomplish is to make a dynamic group by where it will take into consideration the other parameter.

Expected OUTPUT:

```
 STARTDATETIME             |         STOPDATETIME          |      ID    | SUM(EVENT)
2019-05-05T05:00:00Z              2019-05-05T06:00:00Z            1        2
2019-05-05T07:00:00Z              2019-05-05T08:00:00Z            1        1
2019-05-05T05:00:00Z              2019-05-05T06:00:00Z            2        0
2019-05-05T07:00:00Z              2019-05-05T08:00:00Z            2        3
2019-05-05T08:00:00Z              2019-05-05T10:00:00Z            2        0
```

Comment: join != group, those are 2 different things. Please update your question with what you have tried (the sql query), the actual input, and expected output.

Comment: Where's your query???

Comment: Read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'm sorry, i thought it was clear, i have updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
      r.ID
      ,r.STARTDATETIME
      ,r.STOPDATETIME
      ,Sum(e.EVENT) as [SUM(Event)]
  FROM dbo.GroupDatetimeRanges as r
  Left Join dbo.GroupDatetimeEvents as e
  on r.ID = e.ID and e.EVENTDATETIME between r.STARTDATETIME and r.STOPDATETIME
  Group By 
        r.ID
      ,r.STARTDATETIME
      ,r.STOPDATETIME
```

Results

```
ID  STARTDATETIME           STOPDATETIME           SUM(Event)
1   2019-05-05T05:00:00Z    2019-05-05T06:00:00Z    2
1   2019-05-05T07:00:00Z    2019-05-05T08:00:00Z    1
2   2019-05-05T05:00:00Z    2019-05-05T06:00:00Z    NULL
2   2019-05-05T07:00:00Z    2019-05-05T08:00:00Z    3
2   2019-05-05T08:00:00Z    2019-05-05T10:00:00Z    NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
select
      f.StartDateTime
    , f.StopDateTime
    , f.ID
    , Qty = sum(
      case 
        when s.EventDatetime between f.StartDateTime and f.StopDateTime
        then s.Event 
        else 0 
      end)
from FirstTable f
left join SecondTable s on (s.ID = f.ID)
group by f.StartDateTime, f.StopDateTime, f.ID
```